# Error 403 This action is unauthorized. with provider in Laravel

Tags: laravel

Hi everyone Good evening . 
I am practicing with laravel but i have error.
I am not sure cuz i have a error 403 .
I am using provider!!
this is method get the id from user and use $this->authorize($user);

```
 public function edit($id){
        // buscar usuario en la base de datos y evitar
        // la insercion de datos nulos
        $user = User::findorFail($id);
        $this->authorize($user);
        return view('users.edit', compact('user')); 
    }
```

After In the class called PoliticaUsuario has method called "edit" where I wanna compare users but return false and  I get error 403 or This action is unauthorized.!

```
class PoliticaUsuario
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    /**
     * Create a new policy instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function edit(User $auth, User $user ){        
        return $auth->id === $user->id;
    }


}
```

Obviously, this is Provider where I insert my class called PoliticaUsuario and the User Model

```
class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
        User::class => PoliticaUsuario::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        //
    }
}
```

[this is the photo from database :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VL2TJ.png)
Pardon for my English I am still studying !!

Comment: what version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @lagbox exactly!! but a person helped to me right now!! thanks!!

Comment: @lagbox 7.15.0 !!! :) its very interesting laravel!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still need to pass the method name like this

```
$this->authorize('edit', $user);
```